# Wifi won't connect when SSID has space character?

Tags: wi-fi, wpa2

When trying to connect to a WPA2 network from an HTC Hero running 2.1, I can't connect if the hidden SSID has a space in the name.

Has anyone else encountered this problem?  Is it known to be an Android issue?

Comment: It's not so convenient that HTC phones have 'HTC Network' as the default, is it? ;)

Comment: I've never had this problem on my android device (note3) but my wife and daughter's iphone 6 and 6s couldn't connect when there was a space in the ssid. I changed the ssid to have no spaces and they could connect perfectly (Nov'17).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes and yes.  http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8035

I haven't seen any resolution to this except changing the router's SSID if you have access to it.

Comment: Thanks!  I hunched the space was the problem and ended up changing the SAID, but was never sure it was really a bug with Android or not.

Comment: Its not so bad when its your AP and can change it but they really need to fix thnugbug.

Comment: Fortunately the AP I was having a problem with had a guest SSID option.  We just added the second SSID and were able to connect without affecting the other established users.